# avaiability of public-domain platform/os vectors

Tags: website-design, vector

I have looked high and low for platform logos (iOS, Android, Unity 3D, Haxe, Java, .NET, etc.) in a vector or even photo format that have a consistent look and feel.

Short of collecting disparate logos from each brand, re-sizing and making consistent, is there a good resource or site where I might look?

I realize this is probably trivial to do from scratch for most here, unfortunately I can't say the same for myself.

Comment: Corporate logos in use by corporations would never be considered public-domain. That's not to say someone hasn't created them for you to use freely, but don't confuse that with public domain. The best way to find these is to check with each company and see if they have a 'media/press' section on their site. They often will offer downloadable images for your use, including logos.

Comment: I get that public-domain was a bad choice of wording. As for the media/press section, yes that is were I'm at now and have a bunch of disparate logos that I need to merge into a more symmetric/normalized looking group. Ideally I would like a single sprite-sheet of these images already normalized with CSS. This way I could slice n' dice each platform logo as I need it.

Comment: I think you'll have to DIY. Get the logos, put them in to one sprite image, and then consider ways to 'normalize' the looks. One way may simply be to convert them all to grayscale and/or colorize them all with the same monotone tint.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, you are probably right since I can't find anything similar out there.